# Canon Pixma MG5650 Printer on Ubuntu 32bit

Tags: printing, canon

I have Ubuntu 14LTS on a 32bit computer and a Canon Pixma MG5650 printer/scanner. 
I'm only finding drivers needing 64bit Ubuntu. Does anyone know how to make it work... if it can be made to work... with 32bit?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was easier than I thought. Rather than trying the hard way, by seeking to download a driver before connecting the printer to the laptop, I ended up simply plugging it all together, and going through "System settings" at screen top right. It found what it needed for itself, when guided to "Canon MG 5600 series", and now seems to be talking to the printer.
Serves me right for not just trusting it to sort itself out!

Comment: and Canon do supply (32 and 64)printer drivers for the MG5600 series devices; (as they do for seemingly all their inkjets these days); the Ubuntu package comes down as cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html and it has an install script to 1) install the drivers and 2) register the device on lpadmin and if one saves the package as it is downloaded the commands would be `cd Downloads` and `tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz` and `cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb` and `sudo ./install.sh` and then watch the terminal  for questions;